# Is there any way to groupby and calculate statistical measures all in one step?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I know I can calculate **unique count, mean, median, kurtosis**, and **skewness** individually and merge into one dataframe, but that's a lot of steps comparing to R data.table, where you can just calculate all these in one step. Is there any way I can do a `groupby` and calculate all these in one step in Python as well?

```
df <- data[,.(ItemCount= uniqueN(Item),
             Median_val = median(Value),
             Avg_val = mean(Value),
             Skew_val = skewness(Value),
             Kurt_val = kurtosis(Value)),.(Year, Category)][order(Year,Category)]
```

Comment: Does [Applying multiple functions at once](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) help?

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps. The "Named Aggregation" section is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RootTwo's referrence link provided in the comment section, I was able to solve my own question. Note that for kurtosis, we cannot use `aggfunc="kurt"`. It will return an error" `'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'kurt'`

Below is my solution:

```
df = (data.groupby(['Year', 'Category'], as_index=False)
      .agg(ItemCount = pd.NamedAgg(column="Item", aggfunc="nunique"), 
           mean = pd.NamedAgg(column="Value", aggfunc="mean"),
           median = pd.NamedAgg(column="Value", aggfunc="median"), 
           skew = pd.NamedAgg(column="Value", aggfunc="skew"),  
           kurt =  pd.NamedAgg(column="Value", aggfunc=pd.DataFrame.kurt))
      )
```